# Showing the last character of a password in an EditText

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

I have an app where people need to login with a password. I would like for only the last character typed to be shown, but all I seem to get is all chars dots or all chars visible.

I tried a few things:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

and setting inputtype in the xml.

I have only tested on a galaxy s2 as that is the only android device at my office at the moment, so I don't know if the problem is only with my device.

edit:
Just tested on an HTC Sensation from a colleague and it does work as intended on his phone, but the question remains how to get this same thing on the Galaxy S2?

Comment: I believe it is just how the manufacturer implements the system UI, and it just varies device by device, therefore I am pretty confident it is not something that can be change on the developer end.

Comment: I believe this is a device-wide setting and not something you can change in an app. If you select "Visible Passwords" in the "Location and Security settings" menu you can turn this feature on or off.

Comment: You will be surprised if check how your EditText for password in landscape orientation. :)

Comment: meh don't want to see my app in landscape, but guess its a normal thing then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's been almost 1.5 years since this was asked :P. But I had the same requirement and was successfully able to implement it. Pass an object of the MyTransformation class as a parameter in the setTransformationMethod and you're good to go :) Here's the code.

```
public class MyTransformation extends PasswordTransformationMethod{

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
        //This is the check which makes sure the last character is shown
            if(index != mSource.length()-1)
                return '•';
            else
                return mSource.charAt(index);
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i just gave up when it worked on most other devices except my own, but with this piece of code it even works on my device. thanks :)

Comment: i get this error `Cannot resolve this symbol 'MyTransformation'`

Comment: @mrid: bit more detail regarding the error would be helpful. Where exactly do you get this?

Comment: @AndyFaizan i got it working. i was passing `MyTransformation.GetInstance()` instead of `new MyTransformation()`....is there a way to hide the last visible character after, say 1 second ?

Comment: can someone translate this to kotlin?

Comment: nevermind, I tried to convert it to kotlin and it crashed.. 
looks like I must use java instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667607/kotlin-crashes-in-passwordtransformationmethod-while-java-works-fine

Answer (score 2):

Improving on [AndyFaizan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057069/andyfaizan)'s answer, my solution doesn't show characters while using backspace.
Without this (simple) change it'd be possible to reveal the whole password by deleting characters at the end of the input.

```
public class CustomPasswordTransformation extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    boolean lastActionWasDelete = false;

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        this.lastActionWasDelete = before > count;
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence source;

        PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        public char charAt(int index) {
            //This is the check which makes sure the last character is shown
            if (!lastActionWasDelete && index == source.length() - 1) return source.charAt(index);
            return '•';
        }

        public int length() {
            return source.length(); // Return default
        }

        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return source.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036608/ethan) already mentioned ages ago, the user can toggle the password character display behaviour in the system security settings.

To hide the password just use

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

the rest is taken care of by the operation system.

In my case i wondered about different behaviour on a variation of devices.
After some investigation the security setting 'Visible Passwords' was turned off on the device which did not show the last character.

If you must ignore the system wide setting, [AndyFaizan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057069/andyfaizan) 's password transformation solution is still the way to go.